# python error wheel while installing packages

Tags: python, pip

The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

```
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vl7cs7d8\pillow_b1e69e937cae422cb43abf0a9527a8e6\setup.py", line 852, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 108, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 325, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vl7cs7d8\pillow_b1e69e937cae422cb43abf0a9527a8e6\setup.py", line 687, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  RequiredDependencyException: zlib

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vl7cs7d8\pillow_b1e69e937cae422cb43abf0a9527a8e6\setup.py", line 903, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I get this error when installing any package like matplotlib, pillow, etc. It always gives me this @wheel@ error.

Comment: Try upgrading your pip and if you have issues with wheel when installing any library using pip then try `pip install wheel`

Comment: nothing happens, everything showed the same error @KeerthithejaS.C.